# In Flutter "final response = await http.get(url);" I am getting an error in the url part of the code

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http

I am getting an error in the url part of the code, I have shown the error in the screenshot. How can I fix my code without changing its function.

[image: error message]

```
Future<List<Articles>?> getNews() async {

String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
final response = await http.get(url);

if (response.body.isEmpty) {
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  News news = News.fromJson(responseJson);
  return news.articles;
}
return null;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass Uri instead of string.

```dart
 final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
```

Comment: I am facing this kind of issue, could it be related to your solution elsewhere?

[error][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZuSI.png

Comment: That is related to null safety issue, do a null check and provide string

Comment: I did, but I still get a warning. [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vZPU.png)

Comment: I need to check more code, you can create separate question with providing necessary snippet? And avoid pasting code-image, provide code-snippet that will reproduce the issue.

Comment: Btw, does this one solve your  question issue?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what to do.

Comment: About current question or new? About URL issue, do as I've answered.  And the new one will be `if(articles[index].urlImage!=null)Image.network(articles[index].urlToImage)`

Comment: If the solution is like this, this also gives an error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTLLy.png)

Comment: Oh forgot to add `!`, do `if(articles[index].urlImage!=null)Image.network(articles[index].urlToImage!)`  Check more [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: (if(articles[index].urlImage!=null)) gives an error in the urlImage part in this section and corrects it as urlToImage. There is no problem in this part, but this time my code does not work. Normally, it should pull images from the API service.

Comment: Can you debug the app if you are getting data or not. else you can [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a different question providing the necessary snippet that will reproduce the issue

Comment: I guess it can't access the data.  [debug](https://imgur.com/Q7Brnk8)

Comment: I think this answers deserve to be accepted before jumping into another question...

Answer (score 1):

You can assign uri something like this

```
var uri= Uri.https('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 'posts');
```

And if you want to add queryparametrs then use below code

```
final queryParameters =
    {
      'key' : 'value',
    };
    var uri= Uri.https('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 'posts',queryParameters);
```

And use this uri in place of Url.

```
final response = await http.get(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove that http. before get() and pass Uri like this:

```
String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
final response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
```